# Animating full menu dropdown with Jquery

Tags: jquery

Im having some trouble animating my full menu dropdown. I just want it to slide down just a bit slower than the default state.

This is my Jquery for show the menu:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.megamenu').hover(
   function(){
       $(this).addClass('show');
       $(this).closest('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideToggle();
},
   function(){ $(this).removeClass('show') }
);
```

});

I tried to add the "closest" to the function because I want to find the closest ul that is named "dropdown-menu" and animate it. How can I solve this in a simple way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can define an animation's duration in `.slideToggle( [duration ] )`. Read from the official [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/).

*P.s: The duration is in miliseconds.*

Comment: Yes but the problem is that the animation doesn't work at all.